# Iteriate through JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "Type1": "tyyype1",
  "type2": "type22",
  "entry": [
    {
      "Url": "0000",
      "resource": {
        "Type3": "GYM",
        "id": "3",
        "extension": [
          {
            "url": "33",
            "Int": 5
          }
        ],
        "identifier": [
          {
            "sys": "7",
            "val": "9"
          }
        ],
        "case": F,
        "name": [
          {
            "family": "doe",
            "given": [
              "alex"
            ],
            "pre": [
              "coach"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "address": [
          {
            "street": [
              "5696 gold gym rd"
            ],
            "city": "San Fran",
            "state": "CA",
            "postalCode": "55667",
            "country": "US"
          }
        ],
        "g": "f"
      },
```

How do I iterate through this to get the "name" with everything included in the name and "address", just the street, I want a for loop that would work for this

Comment: First thing you do is to parse the JSON into a JavaScript object. I suppose you really have JSON, right? Like the description of the `json` tag states?

Comment: I'd like to challenge the closing of this question. This is JSON, not an object yet.

Comment: Also, you should add your code, and pinpoint where in that code things don't go as you expect...

Comment: @JonasEberle, see the addition to the closure links.

Comment: @trincot yes, that's ok for me like that.